# i have question about asynchronous programming at flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-async

```
void main() async {
  check();
  print('end');
}

Future check() async {
  var version = lookUpVersion();
  print(version);
}

int lookUpVersion() {
  return 12;
}
```

```dart
void main() async {
  check();
  print('end');
}

Future check() async {
  var verion = await lookUpVersion();

  print(version);
}

int lookUpVersion() {
  return 12;
}
```

These two code only have one difference, await keyword.

I wonder that why not did they wait for main function code? even I used Future+async keyword at first code.

Can you explain about this?

Comment: lookUpVersion method is not a future in second code. no need to use async await

Answer (score 0):

The async and await keywords provide a declarative way to define asynchronous functions and use their results.

For first one - result will be

```
//12
//end
```

For second one - result will be

```
//end
//12
```

Which means if you add await it will become asynchronous.